# hystrix - weird threading behaviour when using .toObservable()

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, hystrix

I have a set of HystrixCommand wrapping a blocking IO operation (a JAX-WS web service client call), that I wanted to compose as observables (using merge on the list), so I use toObservable() on the command and schedule it on Schedulers.io().

What I'm seeing from both the app server logs and the dashboard is that all the WS calls seem to be running on the first thread of the hystrix pool for that command, but execution time seem to be consistent with them being run concurrently, on different threads.

Is this something to be expected that has something to do with the CachedThreadScheduler being used by Schedulers.io() or have I misconfigured something (using thread isolation with coreSize 0 and maxSize 10)? furthermore, if this is true, should I use semaphore isolation instead, even if my workload is blocking?

Comment: just for reference: the behavior described is the expected one with the configuration I was using: thread pools tend to fill up the queue before increasing the number of threads past their core size. Since I set a core size of 0 and I was scheduling a number smaller than the queue length, only one job was being executed at a time.